# Running a Gradle project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Using the Eclipse "Import" function from the Eclipse "File
   menu" I have imported a "Project" of type "Gradle".
I browsed using the import wizard to my projects "root" 
   directory.  Then I clicked the "Build model" button.
I Checked all check boxes and then rebuilt the dependencies by right clicking on the project
   and then choose

Gradle-->Refresh All Dependencies

Then I chose

Run As-->External Tools Configuration" and Configured a new "clean" and "build"
   configuration for running a sub-project.

I got a warning

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in  conjunction with -source 1.5
```

why am I getting the above warning?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that as of Gradle 1.0RC1 (and a version of the eclipse plugin which supports it), there is a java home setting in the gradle eclipse plugin preferences:

`Gradle --> Arguments --> Java Home --> Workspace JRE`

This worked for me in getting the build to use the right JDK, despite explicitly adding a sourceCompatibility in my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a conflict of JDK versions. Go to

```
Preferences --> Java --> Compiler
```

and make sure that your source compatability (and probably compiler compliance and Generated .class files compatability, just to be sure) are what you expected.

Then, check that

```
Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs
```

has a matching JRE, and that it is activated.